How to say "I would have loved to cycle a bit longer"?
The Japan loving father of a Dutch friend will pass away soon and we are making a memorial/funeral card. We would like to translate the sentence "I would have loved to cycle a bit longer..." (expressing a melancholic wish/desire that can no longer be fulfilled). Cycling is a daily activity in the life of Dutch people.
What do you think about these? Or any better suggestion?

自転車でもう少し旅を続けて欲しかった
もう少し自転車に乗れればよかったのに
もっとサイクリングに行きたかった


Your three suggestions are already grammatically perfect, and the ultimate choice is up to you. But let me share how I feel about these sentences as a native Japanese speaker.

旅 ("travel/journey") implies traveling a long distance, and 続ける ("continue") implies the father did so until recently. Can he be considered a traveler? Even if not, people might naturally interpret 旅 as a metaphor for life and understand it that way...
While this use of のに is grammatically correct, it might sound overly negative as it clearly evokes the reality that he can no longer ride a bicycle. It's somewhat like the sentence ends with "however", e.g., "I wish you could ___, however...".
Since no subject is implied, this could be interpreted as expressing the father's own feelings (i.e., "I wish I could cycle a bit longer"). Consider changing it to もっとあなたとサイクリングに行きたかった or もっとサイクリングに行ってほしかった to avoid any ambiguity.

As an alternative, instead of expressing regret for what couldn't be, using expressions of gratitude like these might feel more natural to the eyes of a native Japanese speaker:

楽しそうにサイクリングする姿が忘れられません
サイクリングを通じて、たくさんの思い出をありがとう
自転車に乗る姿がとても素敵でした

